# What layout will be the best

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-activity, android-edittext

I used relative layout - tablelayout as in the following image:

[image]

But I want to know if I use linear layout in linear layout where imageview should be left side n rest all textview n edit text to right n IMG view should take 25% other should cover 75%
So what will be the best layout for my app?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use Linear Layout. Using the Linear layout Weight property you can almost cover up your desired UI. So depending upon the screen sizes you can have a good interface. Since you are looking for 25% and 75% of the screen create a layout weight sum of 1 and give layout weight to each child layout 0.25 and 0.75. Let me know if it works or not

Comment: Well try this and let u know

Comment: just use linear in linear layout

Comment: Yeah use layout weight property so that you can give the 75:25 ratio for your content